# Struts2 - Linking to external URL on JSP *excluding* local context path?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2

Using Struts2, I compute a link in my java code and expose the link's string in a getter for the JSP page. I try to link to this external link using `<a href='<s:property value="mylink" />'>a Link</a>`. Sadly, Struts always puts the local context before this link, so the resulting link looks like `<a href="http://localhost:8080/Mycontext/https://twitter.com/some?more=param&ete=rs">a Link</a>`.

Note: I also tried using `<s:a>` and `<s:url>` with `includeContext="false"` ... same result. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Struts always puts the local context before this link`

uh? If you really write a plain `<a ... >` element

```
<a href='<s:property value="mylink" />'>a Link</a>
```

in your jsp, then Struts2 will **not** add anything, Struts2 does not even know that there is a link there, the `property` tag is just a general *"echo the value of this property"* instruction. You can check that by copying the same tag `<s:property value="mylink" />` outside the A element. Either you are computing that property wrong in your action, or either you are not writing that jsp fragment but using some Struts2 tag related with links (`<s:a>` or `<s:url>`).

BTW, if you want to place an external link, unrelated to your application, the first option (a plain A element, not a Struts2 link tag) seems the right way.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't computing the URL correctly - in fact I did URL-encode the whole URL, which made the "http://" in the beginning invalid. But Struts2 (or the JSP itself?) seems to realize that there's an <a> tag with an ill defined href attribute and then prepends the context. Thanks :-)

Comment: Did you really looked inside the generated html content, to assert that the context was prepended? Perhaps what happened is that the link was relative (lacked the http://... ) and so the browser -implicitly- added the current context.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the generated HTML and indeed the http:// was missing (instead httpandsomeASCIIcodes were in the beginning of the URL), so I guess instead of just leaving the relative URL in there, Struts2 transformed with into an absolute URL using the appcontext. Can't say I like that "feature".